# ReferenceError: SVG is not defined in Jest Tests

Tags: angular, jestjs, svg.js

I have the component where i connected these libs and use some of the filter and drag-n-drop features:

```
import { Box, Container, Shape, SVG, Image } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js';
import '@svgdotjs/svg.draggable.js';
import '@svgdotjs/svg.filter.js';
```

and I have the `spec.ts` for this component where only connect this:

```
import { SVG, Container } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js';
```

Then i get this error when run Jest tests:

```
ReferenceError: SVG is not defined

  4 | // import * as SVGFilter from '@svgdotjs/svg.filter.js';
> 6 | import '@svgdotjs/svg.draggable.js';
    | ^
  8 | import '@svgdotjs/svg.filter.js';
```

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: Second question I see with problems according jest and svg.js. Make sure that you either use modules everywhere or requires everywhere. try not to mix it. it seems to take the browser version which expects a global SVG instead of the module version which just imports SVG itself

Comment: The way the code is written in this question it looks like no mixing is happening - imports are being used both in the production code and the test.

@Fuzzyma do you have any other ideas about what might be going on here? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: Use type:module in your package.json maybe? Jest had its own module resolution I guess. You can also explicitly try to import the esm version `'@svgdotjs/svg.js/dist/svg.esm.js'`